# Drawing circles: separation of code into classes

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw circles with random colors and random diameters on `mousePressed` event but I'm having some issues when I tried to organize my code a little bit "separate my code into classes".

### Controller class

```
public class Controller implements MouseListener {
private HashSet<Circle> circleSet = new HashSet<>();
private int r,g,b,d;

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    r = new Random().nextInt(256);
    g = new Random().nextInt(256);
    b = new Random().nextInt(256);
    d = 10+new Random().nextInt(100);

    circleSet.add(new Circle(e.getX()-d/2,e.getY()-d/2,d,d,new 
    Color(r,g,b),0,0));
}

public HashSet<Circle> getCircleSet() {
    return circleSet;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

### View class

```
public class View extends JPanel{
Controller controller;
HashSet<Circle> circleHashSet;
public View() {
    repaint();
    controller = new Controller();
    circleHashSet = controller.getCircleSet();
    this.addMouseListener(controller);
    listen();

    System.out.println(circleHashSet.size());
}

public void listen() {
    new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            circleHashSet = controller.getCircleSet();
            System.out.println(circleHashSet.size());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    for (Circle circle:this.circleHashSet) {
        paintCircle(g,circle);
    }
    System.out.println(circleHashSet);
}

public void paintCircle(Graphics graphics, Circle circle) {
    graphics.setColor(circle.color);
    graphics.fillOval(circle.x,circle.getY(),circle.a,circle.b);
}
```

`circleHashSet` still empty even though I did:

```
//circleHashSet = controller.getCircleSet();
```

Circles are added into `circleSet` after pressing the mouse but I can't get them into the `View` class.

Comment: The view should contain the data that needs to be painted, not the controller. So when you create the controller you need to pass it a reference to the view. Then you need a method in the view class like `addCircle(...)` that will 1) add the circle to the set and 2) repaint() the panel using the new circle. Also you should use an ArrayList to hold the cicles, not a HashSet. As you iterate through the HashSet the order of painting the circles can change as you add more circles to the set. This should not happen in a painting method.

Comment: i did that but how i will refer to the controller

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the problem is that you are calling the `paintComponents(Graphics g)` method instead of the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

If you are done changing this, you should create a separate `Circle` POJO class for the circles, because the only avaliable Circle avaliable in the basic Java API is from the JavaFX package.

After setting the constructor for the circle class, you can add to the `HashSet` more easily. Like so: `circleSet.add(new Circle(e.getX() - d / 2, e.getY() - d / 2, d, new Color(r, g, b)));`

Another problem is that the `Timer` object you created is never used for anything. First, you should make a `Timer` object and after initializing it, call the `start()` method on it to start the checking of the circles.

Answer (score -1):

put this line of code

```
    circleHashSet = controller.getCircleSet();
```

within `paintComponents()` method. The reason is that you only get the value of HashSet when you start the program while the hashset is empty at this time. You should renew the value of `circleHashSet` after painting one with mouse.

Comment: This is guaranteed to fail. The HashSet variable is a reference variable.