# repeating objects in text file

Tags: java, swing, filewriter

my code is about creating circles with random colors and random diameters and then saving all circles information into text file so that when i execute the program in the future i find all the circles that i created in the past so i have create a Circle class which contain all circle information x and y diameter colors and also dx and dy because "i will move those circles in the future using java swing timer"
i have also create a View class and controller class and WriteFile class the problem i'm facing is that when i call saveCircles() method inside paintComponent() method it keeps repeating circles inside my text file even though i have added my circles into a hashSet and i have also overided equals() and hashCode()

View class`public class View extends JPanel {
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    HashSet myCircleHashSet = new HashSet<>();

```
public View() {
    this.addMouseListener(controller);
}



@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    myCircleHashSet = controller.getMyCircleSet();
    for (MyCircle myCircle : this.myCircleHashSet) {
        paintCircle(g, myCircle);
    }
    repaint();
    saveCircle();
}

public void paintCircle(Graphics graphics, MyCircle myCircle) {
    graphics.setColor(myCircle.color);
    graphics.fillOval(myCircle.x, myCircle.getY(), myCircle.a, myCircle.b);
}

public void saveCircle() {
    System.out.println(this.myCircleHashSet.size());
    try {
        new WriteFile(myCircleHashSet);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

Controller class

```
public class Controller implements MouseListener {
private HashSet<MyCircle> myCircleSet = new HashSet<>();
private int r, g, b, d;

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    r = new Random().nextInt(256);
    g = new Random().nextInt(256);
    b = new Random().nextInt(256);
    d = 10 + new Random().nextInt(100);

    myCircleSet.add(new MyCircle(e.getX() - d / 2, e.getY() - d / 2, d, d, new
            Color(r, g, b), 0, 0));
}

public HashSet<MyCircle> getMyCircleSet() {
    return myCircleSet;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
```

}

WriteFile class

```
public class WriteFile {
FileWriter fileWriter;
PrintWriter pw;
HashSet<MyCircle> circleHashSet;

public WriteFile(HashSet<MyCircle> circleHashSet) throws IOException {
    this.circleHashSet = circleHashSet;
    fileWriter = new FileWriter("test.txt",true);
    pw = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (MyCircle circle:circleHashSet) {
        pw.println(circle);
    }
    pw.close();
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: You should not be using a HashSet as suggested in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583772/drawing-circles-separation-of-code-into-classes. Why should we take the time to answer if you don't listen to suggestions?

Comment: i'm sorry but i used hashSet just to avoid repeating the same objects in the text file no i will not to put save circles in paintComponent  and i will change hashSet into arrayList

Answer (score 0):

> the problem i'm facing is that when i call saveCircles() method inside paintComponent() method it keeps repeating circles inside my text file even though i have added my circles into a hashSet and i have also overided equals() and hashCode()

The paintComponent() method is for painting only. There should be no program logic in that method. You can't control when or how often the paintComponent() method gets called.

The circles should be written to the file when you create the circle or change a property of the circle. Or you need to add logic to save the state of your program when you close the program.

```
repaint();
```

NEVER invoke repaint() from within the paintComponent() method. This will create a continuous loop wasting CPU.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot camickr i finally solved that issue by adding a window listener like that:

```
  this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            super.windowClosing(windowEvent);
            view.saveCircle();
        }
    });
```

and i have added repaint() to mouseListener event

```
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    r = new Random().nextInt(256);
    g = new Random().nextInt(256);
    b = new Random().nextInt(256);
    d = 10 + new Random().nextInt(100);

    myCircleSet.add(new MyCircle(e.getX() - d / 2, e.getY() - d / 2, 
    d, d, new
            Color(r, g, b), 0, 0));
    view.repaint();

}
```